# angular directive to show a hint div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am trying to create some DIVs and each one has a DIV having a hint about that parent DIV, the html layout looks like this:

```
<div show-hint>
    <h2>Title1</h2>
    <div class="hint">This is description 1</div>
</div>

<div show-hint>
    <h2>Title2</h2>
    <div class="hint">This is description 2</div>
</div>

<div show-hint>
    <h2>Title3</h2>
    <div class="hint">This is description 3</div>
</div>
```

Now what i want to achieve is when i press on 1 of the DIVs, the child DIV with hint should show and all the others hide, and when i press outside any of the DIVs, all the hints should disapear. I created a directive that looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('showHint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                elem.toggleClass('showhint');
            });
            $(document).bind('click', function() {
                elem.removeClass('showhint');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This directive opens the hint that i press on, makes all hints disapear when i press outside any of the DIVs, but when i open a hint and i press on another hint, it opens both of them and i dont know how to make the other hints disapear when i open 1 of them. Also i know this is not the 'angular way', incase there is a better approach i would love to see it.

I hope anyone can help, thanks in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a nice solution:

- Only One event listener on the document.
- One more event listener on each element.
- And a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zAJwovXFAUYMWC4Yn78J?p=preview)

#### Solution:

```
app.directive('showHint',  function() {

    var removeClass = function(){
      var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('showhint')
      angular.element(divs).removeClass('showhint');
    }

    angular.element(document).on('click', function(){
      removeClass();
    });

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

            elem.bind('click', function(event) {
                var hasClass = elem.hasClass('showhint');
                removeClass();
                if (!hasClass) elem.addClass('showhint');
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a event propagation problem

```
app.directive('showHint', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                elem.toggleClass('showhint');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(document).bind('click', function() {
                elem.removeClass('showhint');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rb32H/)

Comment: yes, i have added that, but the problem is when i open an hint, the other hint still stays opened and it should disapear, only 1 hint should be open at 1 point

Comment: this is a nice way to achieve my goal, thank you very much Arun P Johny!

Answer (score -1):

```
elem.bind('click', function() {
    elem.addClass('showhint').siblings().removeClass('showhint'); 
       // remove the class from the other sibling divs
});
```